# Custom Workflow Activity - Get Warnings from Build Details

Tags: c#, build, workflow-activity, custom-activity

Ok, here's the thing:

I'm driving myself nuts trying to get the WARNINGS from a **IBuildDetail** object when invoking a **CustomActivity**.

This is what I've tried:

```
private static List<IBuildInformationNode> GetBuildWarnings(IBuildDetail buildInformation)
{
    var warnings = buildInformation.Information.GetNodesByType(InformationTypes.BuildWarning);

    if (warnings.Count == 0 && buildInformation.CompilationStatus == BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded)
    {
        buildInformation.RefreshAllDetails();
        warnings = buildInformation.Information.GetNodesByType(InformationTypes.BuildWarning);
    }
    return warnings;
}
```

That gives me **0 WARNINGS**.

I've also tried the same code using :

```
var warnings = InformationNodeConverters.GetBuildWarnings(buildInformation);
```

which still brings no warnings.

This CustomActivity is invoked at the end of the Workflow: I actually don't have any issues retrieving the rest of the details like build status, build errors, test information, etc.

The issue is **only with the Warnings**.

Funny thing is that, at the end of the build, when I check the build results, **there ARE warnings**.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same problem, and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the warnings are happening *after* your custom activity is run. Can you examine the build log and see exactly where the warnings occur?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can see the warnings in the msbuild log file already, which is previous to my custom activity invocation. 
I also see them in the Build Details in Visual Studio, when I double click the run build, right in the Summary.
Another data is that I have a separate console and I'm querying the build definitions programmatically (out of the workflow/customactivity) and I'm having the same result: no warnings, rest of the build details are fine.

Answer (score 0):

*buildDetail.Information.GetNodesByType(InformationTypes.BuildWarning)* does not return what you're looking for because messages from tracking participant are not flushed immediately.

*InformationNodeConverters.GetBuildWarnings* internally calls GetNodesByType(), thus it won't work for same reason.

Original information is kept in internal field of TrackingParticipant, thus it is inaccessible. Anyway, if you wait >15seconds, information from this internal field is flushed to accessible field.

Thus the ugly hack that does the job seems to be:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(16000);
var trackingParticipant = context.GetExtension<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking.BuildTrackingParticipant>();
var warnings = GetWarnings(trackingParticipant.GetActivityTracking(context));


    private List<IBuildInformationNode> GetWarnings(IActivityTracking activityTracking ){
        IBuildInformationNode rootNode = getRootNode( activityTracking.Node );
        return rootNode.Children.GetNodesByType(InformationTypes.BuildWarning, true);
    }

    private IBuildInformationNode getRootNode( IBuildInformationNode  node)
    {
        while( node.Parent != null ) node = node.Parent;
        return node;
    }
```